# Tensorflow - When using tf.contrib.layers.conv2d, can I set the name of the weights and biases?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow version: 1.10.1

I want to transfer my learned weights and biases of the convolution layers in my pretrained network to a new network.

However, because I used `conv2d` api, the weights and biases in the checkpoint file are automatically named as `Conv/weights`,`Conv/biases`,`Conv_1/weights`,`Conv_1/biases`,`Conv_2/weights`,`Conv_2/biases` etc.

However, these names are not consistent with my variable name in my codes. 
For example, `Conv/weights`,`Conv/biases` belongs to a variable named `C2` in my codes, so I want to name them as `C2/weights`,`C2/biases`.

I know for varibales defined by `get_variable`, I can set their names to whatever strings I want by `my_varibale = tf.get_variable("whatever_name_I_want",shape,dtype,initializer)`, where `my_variable` is named to `"whatever_name_I_want"`.

However, when it comes to `my_layer = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(params_blabla)` (or the equivalent api in `tf.nn` or `tf.layers`), I don't know how I can name `my_layer`.

**So, is it possible to do this? And if possible, how?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [tf.layers.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Conv2D) and [tf.nn.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) you can pass an additional parameter called `name`.

**Example:**

```
my_conv1 = tf.layers.conv2D(...., name='my_conv1')
my_conv2 = tf.layers.conv2D(...., name='my_conv2 ')
```

For [tf.contrib.layers.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/conv2d) the parameter `scope`is used to namespace your layers.

**Example:**

```
with tf.name_scope('my_conv1') as scope:
    my_conv1 = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(..., scope=scope)
```

**Result:**

In all cases your weights and biases are named like for example `my_conv1/weights` and `my_conv1/bias`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see `name` in `tf.contrib.layers` and thought `tf.nn` and `tf.layers` should be similar. It turned out that I should've read the documentations more carefully before I asked this question.